# Migrating from meteor 1.8.3 to 2.6

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, meteor

I have an old project and I want to use MongoDB 5 which is supported by Meteor 2.6 and the current software that I'm using is on version 1.8.3.
I understand and see the changelog and migration guide.
I want to understand if,
Can I go directly from 1.8.3 to 2.6 ?
OR
Do I need to do this incrementally from 1.8.3. to 1.9 to 2.0 ... 2.6 ?

Comment: Either is fine of course. It's just a matter of how much debugging you are willing to do. So this becomes more of a matter of opinion. If you ask me: I would look at all the major changes in the migration guides and then plan to do at least a few intermediate steps. Otherwise it will be too hard to track down the source of issues you will inevitably see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [ChangeLog](https://docs.meteor.com/changelog#v2620220201) and the [migration guide](https://guide.meteor.com/2.8-migration.html)
Incrementally was the way to go for me.